# Why was nabidh mixing fresh dates with dry forbidden?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

There are a number of *ahadith* wherein the prophet explicitly forbade making [*nabidh*](http://sunnah.com/urn/249031) by mixing dates with grapes, or by mixing old dates with fresh.  While the grapes prohibition might be understood to avoid inadvertently making wine, I don't understand why mixing fresh with old dates is also forbidden.

Why was this mixture brought up in particular?  What is the wisdom behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is simple because [nabidh النَّبِيذَ](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%91%D9%8E%D8%A8%D9%90%D9%8A%D8%B0%D9%8E/) or an-nabidah is a drink or a wine made with fermented dates or grapes put into or mixed with water (or some water mixed with dates/grapes in different sedateness states, which were left for a while ... even until they get fermented)!

> [النَّبِيذُ](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/home.php?word=%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%91%D9%8E%D8%A8%D9%90%D9%8A%D8%B0%D9%8E%20&lang_name=ar-ar&type_word=0&dspl=0) : شُرابٌ مُسكر يُتَّخَذُ من عصير العنب أَو التمر أَو غيرهما ، ويُترَكُ حتى يختمر والجمع : أنْبذَةٌ

Therefore our Messenger (peace be upon him) told the sahaba (May Allah pleased with them) to use instead of fermented dates: grapes or dates or unripe dates without mixing as when they are mixed one couldn't distinguish by taste whether it is fermented yet or not! So one would drink alcohol without being conscious of doing this! For this reason they have been asked to make a drink from non mixed fruits!

I could only find an [Arabic Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/ar/183149) and [explanation](http://www.startimes.com/?t=31439689) supporting my answer so far!

And Allah knows best!